# Android gradle: All buildTypes are getting executed at the same time

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I have an android gradle project and I'm trying to configure the **buildTypes** for the same. Here is a part of my `build.gradle`:

```
android {

...

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            println("inside debug...")
        }    
        release {
            println("inside release...")
        }
    }

...
}
```

When I run the **assembleDebug** task from the terminal, I get the output as:

```
inside debug...
inside release...
```

Why is the release block getting printed? What should I do to print only the debug block when I execute assembleDebug task and only the release block when I execute assembleRelease task?

I'm very new to both android and gradle, so any help will be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simple answer is: **they're not**.

Gradle (it's a simplification) works in two phases: *configuration* and *execution*. During *configuration* phase the *whole* script is evaluated - this is why the `println` statements you added do occur in the output.

To verify if both release and debug tasks are run add the following piece of code:

```
assembleDebug << {
   println 'debug run'
}

assembleRelease << {
   println 'release run'
}
```

With `<<` an action is added, which will be executed while task is run. Actions are run during *execution* phase.

Comment: Thanks i understood it now :)

Comment: Some extra reading on the subject if anyone wants it: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html#sec:build_phases